# How to delete entire Node if its element equals to maximum element

Tags: java, binary-tree

How do I delete maximum Node in `Binarytree`. I would like to delete entire Node if its element equals to maximum element. I can return maximum node but I don't know how to delete it. Not in BinarySearchTree.

```
public class MyLinkedBinaryTree extends LinkedBinaryTree {
MyLinkedBinaryTree() {
    super();
}

public void removeMax(BinaryTreeNode t, int i) {
    if ((int) t.element != i && t.rightChild != null && t.leftChild != null) {
        if (t.leftChild != null)
            removeMax(t.leftChild, i);
        if (t.rightChild != null)
            removeMax(t.rightChild, i);
    } else if ((int) root.element == i) {
        root = null;
    }
}

public int findMax(BinaryTreeNode t) {
    if (t == null)
        return 0;
    int res = (int) t.element;
    int lres = findMax(t.rightChild);
    int rres = findMax(t.leftChild);
    if (lres > res)
        res = lres;
    if (rres > res)
        res = rres;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Is this tree ordered (something like [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree))? Or should we assume that the order of elements is random?

Comment: The order of element is random . No ordered like BST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to change `findMax` to return not a value, but an actual node that contains it:

```
//DISCLAIMER: untested code
public BinaryTreeNode findMaxNode(BinaryTreeNode t) {
    if (t == null)
        return null;
    BinaryTreeNode max = t;
    BinaryTreeNode maxLeft = findMax(t.rightChild);
    BinaryTreeNode maxRight = findMax(t.leftChild);
    if (maxLeft!=null && maxLeft.element > t.element) {
        max = maxLeft;
    }
    if (maxRight !=null && maxRight .element > t.element) {
        max = maxRight ;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then you have to figure out how to remove that node from the tree. I assume that it has a link to its parent node. Then we can remove it from its parent, thus removing it from the tree:

```
public void removeMax(BinaryTreeNode t) {
    if(t==null) return;
    BinaryTreeNode max = findMaxNode(t);
    //removing a node from its parent
    BinaryTreeNode parent = max.parent;
    if(parent==null) {
         //figure out what to do is the maximum value is at the root
    } else if(parent.leftChild==max) {
         parent.leftChild = null;
    } else if(parent.rightChild==max) {
         parent.rightChild = null;
    }
}
```

You'll need to figure out what to do when the root holds the maximum and the whole tree is deleted.

If your node doesn't have a reference to its parent, you'll have to update `findMaxNode` to return the parent of a maximum node.

Comment: How i find parent Node ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to only remove the maximum node (and rebranch its children) or remove the node and all its children ?

Also a node should have access to its children but not its root. You need to refactor your code to be able to delete one of the children if its your target (In your case the node wich has the greatest value if I understood well).

Comment: Remove the Node and all its children